# Determine value of infinite series (expected value of N Bernoulli trials until success)

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I know there are a number of posts here that are related to the very same issue. However, I couldn't find a direct answer to this specific question:

Given a Bernoulli experiment, where the probability of success is $\pi$. I'd like to **show** that the expected number of N trials until a first success is:

$$\sum_{N=1}^{\infty} N \pi (1-\pi)^{N-1} = \frac{1}{\pi}$$

(which is, as I understood, simply averaging N by using respective weights as $Bin(N, k=1)$).

Although the result seems logical, I don't see how to calculate the value of this infinite series. My problem is that I think it is a geometric series $\sum ar^n$, but a depends on the index and hence (I believe), I cannot simply say that the result is

$$\frac{a}{1-r}$$

Any hint for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one: if $|x|<1$,

$$\sum_{N=1}^\infty N x^{N-1}=\Bigl(\sum_{N=0}^\infty x^N\Bigr)'=\Bigl(\frac1{1-x}\Bigr)'.$$

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Let $t = 1 - \pi$, so we get

$$\sum_{N=1}^{\infty} N(t-1)t^{N-1} = \sum_{N=1}^{\infty} Nt^{N-1} - \sum_{N=1}^{\infty} Nt^N = \left(\sum_{N=1}^{\infty} t^N\right)' - t \left(\sum_{N=1}^{\infty} t^N\right)'$$

$$\dots = \left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)' - t \left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)' = \frac{1-t}{\left(1-t\right)^2} = \frac{1}{1-t} = 1/\pi$$